# How to show current time in mac terminal prompt?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash

I have this:

```
PS1+="\D{%H:%M:%S}";
```

But this displays the time the prompt started. I want the prompt to show the current 12 hour (not 24 hours) time live (so it keeps changing, and then when a command is made, save that time before going to the next prompt (so, without pressing enter / return on the keyboard). So the time the command was made is saved and visible too.

Is this live updating of a time-based prompt possible?

Comment: Answer might be here (it's for ubuntu): https://askubuntu.com/questions/360063/how-to-show-a-running-clock-in-terminal-before-the-command-prompt

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer: \T is the code for 12hr time in HHH:MM:SS. So, you'll get:

```
$ export PS1+="\T"
08:56:25 $
08:56:26 $
08:56:28 $
08:56:30 $
```

In the case you have the PS1+ is appending onto an earlier configured PS1 variable - you'll need to modify to your needs.

This is a live variable in my version of bash on High Sierra. I copied and pasted above hitting enter to show the seconds incrementing.

Comment: Hi, I wanted a live timer, that changes without pressing enter.

Comment: Just realised that, but that means you need zle in zsh. Also, having had it, it was a pain having it keep refreshing the terminal, and I found checking history easier, and turned it off.

Comment: Yea I am trying to avoid zsh too. It was slow for me when I used it with iterm2. Okay thanks.

Comment: you can just add a digital clock to screen:)

Comment: I just updated my answer with another answer but it requires you to use the z-shell.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a bash shell, add the following line to the .bashrc file (not the .bash_profile file).: `export PROMPT_COMMAND="echo -n \[\$(date +%H:%M:%S)\]\ "`

I just tested this and it works fine. Gives you a prompt like so; [20:58:36]$

This question was asked on StackExchange Ask Ubuntu. The answer was given  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360063/how-to-show-a-running-clock-in-terminal-before-the-command-prompt). It requires using the z-shell which I know you wish to avoid. Maybe this method is faster.

Comment: Hey, does this change live? Like without pressing enter?

Comment: no. every time you hit return it updates.